# How are these Docker setups different? One works and the other not

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm running Postgres image in Docker on an M1 Mac with mapped ports "5432:5432".  My app can connect to the DB from the host machine by calling `localhost:5432`. I'm now trying to run the app within Docker and I'm puzzled by the behavior I see.

This command works:

```
docker run --name api --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway -e DB_HOST=host.docker.internal -p 8000:8000
```

But when I try to replicate the same by putting the api within the docker-compose like this, it doesn't work:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - my-network
  
  api:
    image: api
    environment:
      DB_HOST: host.docker.internal
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Connecting to the DB fails:

> failed to connect to `host=host.docker.internal user=postgres database=postgres`: failed to receive message (unexpected EOF)

I've also tried to put the api container on the same `my-network` network as postgres, and changing the DB host to be the DB container:

```
  api:
    image: api
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
    networks:
      - my-network
```

but that gives me a different error:

> failed to connect to `host=postgres user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp 192.168.192.2:5432: connect: connection refused)

The DB is listening at `IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432` and `IPv6 address "::", port 5432`.  Why would the `docker run` command work but the other two not work?

Comment: In the last case, where you set `DB_HOST=postgres`; if you run `docker-compose up`, without a `-d` option; do you see database initialization messages _after_ the "connection refused" message?  There's a reasonably common problem where applications can start up quickly but a database can take 30-60 seconds to initialize, and you'll get a "connection refused" error in this case.

Comment: (You do not want `host.docker.internal` to connect between containers.)

Comment: @DavidMaze you were right! Waiting a bit worked.  Please put it in an answer if you want to get credit for your solution.  Why did you write that I don't wan't to use `host.docker.internal` to connect between containers?  It has been working through `docker run`.

Comment: It's the Docker equivalent of setting up a port-forwarding rule on your home router and calling that to call some other server on the same system.  You should use the Docker networking system instead – do not set `extra_hosts:` and use the other container name as a host name.

Answer (score 0):

As David figured out the issue in the comments, I would like to suggest `wait-for-it` for such an issue, Instant of waiting a bit then start manually again.

`wait-for-it.sh` usually located at `entrypoint.sh` like this

```
#!/bin/sh
# Wait fot the cassandra db to be ready
./wait-for.sh cassandra:9042 --timeout=0
```

`--timeout=0` , will keep on waiting till cassandra is up and running.

And can be used directly in `docker-compose.yaml` like the following example :

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "cassandra"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "cassandra:9042"]
  db:
    image: cassandra
```

For more information, You can check [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

`Wait-for-it` [github](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)